# Squid configuration to forward another proxy for internet only

Tags: proxy, squid

I just installed squid proxy server on Linux. I am now configurating squid .

I have a set of ip defined for intranet. Internet are those that is not intranet.

If destination is to internet, I want the squid to forward to another proxy which has authetication with login and password.

If destination is intranet , it won't forward to other proxy.

If the destination is to intranet or internet, I want to go through this squid for cacheing purpose.

Comment: Show you existing squid config (without comments).

Comment: @AlexD see answer

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out. I defined a bunch of ips as localnet, for those that are not localnet it will forward to the parentproxy. for those there are localnet, it will be fetch directly

```
cache_peer ipofparentproxy parent 8080 0 no-query default 
cache_peer_access ipofparentproxy allow !localnet
never_direct deny localnet
never_direct allow all

dns_nameservers ipofdnsa, ipofdnsb
```